# Se pierde la variable de session al ver la pagina en un movil en python flask

Tags: javascript, python, html5, flask

Estoy presentado un detalle, cuando visito la página web en un celular se pierde la session, no llega a la siguiente vista pero en una laptop todo marcha bien, no se si se deba al negador o que.

El codigo python:

```
@app.route('/usuario/<id>', methods=['GET'])
def usuario(id):
 fecha_verificacion = str(session['fecha_verificacion'])
 print("FECHA")
 print(fecha_verificacion)


return render_template('usuario.html',id_seguro = id, fecha_verificacion = fecha_nacimiento_verificacion)
```